# Web Service Credentials work from remote but not on the server

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-authentication, credentials, ntlm

I'm calling a web service (named SecurityService) as below:

```
SecurityService.Service securityService = new SecurityService.Service();
securityService.Credentials = networkCredential;

return securityService.GetUserToken();
```

The service has Windows Authentication enabled, nothing else.
This piece of code above works, from remote machines.

When I push this same code out to the IIS server that this service is running on, I get a 401 error:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

I tried the same piece of code with WCF:

```
ServiceSoapClient client = new ServiceSoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;
return client.GetUserToken();
```

with these settings:

```
<binding name="ServiceSoap">
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
  </security>
</binding>
```

Again, on the server, I can't get it to authenticate, from another machine connecting to this server, it works.

Here's the headers captured by advanced logging from the web service:

When it works:

```
sc-win32-status WWW-Authenticate Authorization
2147024891 "NTLM,Negotiate" -
0 - "Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIoAAACi...."
```

When it fails, called from within the same server:

```
sc-win32-status WWW-Authenticate Authorization
2147024891 "NTLM,Negotiate" -
1073741715 "NTLM,Negotiate" "Negotiate ADAAAAGAAYAI4AAACiAaIBpgAAABoAGgBY..."
```

I also got this message instead of the plain 401 error, when I used WCF:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Negotiate'. ---> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

The explanation of Error 1073741715:

```
STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE (-1073741715 (0xC000006D))
The attempted logon is not valid. This is due to either an incorrect user name or incorrect authentication information.
```

Somehow my code is not authenticating to the web service correctly when it is run from within the server.

Here's a link to the same issue. The answer doesn't apply though:

[401 Client 'Negotiate', Server 'Negotiate,NTLM' When Calling WCF Server to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460150/401-client-negotiate-server-negotiate-ntlm-when-calling-wcf-server-to-serve)

Comment: is the web server part of the same windows domain?

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide your user credentials to IIS web app or IIS Application pool which is related with your IIS App.

For this

- Open IIS.
- Click on Application Pools
- Select the application pool which your application works on
- Click on Advanced Properties from the right pane
- Find Identity under Process Model and click on `...` button
- Click on Custom Account and add your windows account there
- Click Ok and save.

also ensure that app does not use custom user. Or alternatively Click on IIS App then click on advanced settings from right pane. After that modify **Physical Path Credentials** and **Physical PAth Credentials Logon Type**

Comment: I'm trying to pass entered credentials through. I can't have a fixed username/password for the application pool.