# LEGACY EDGE ONLY: HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. .'

Tags: iis, windows-10, microsoft-edge, ntlm-authentication, negotiate

I have an application that calls a wcf service, the application uses windows authentication and anonymous access is disabled. I am still getting the error in accessing the service:

**'The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.' '** 
The odd part is that it is working fine in IE11 and chrome (v83), this issue is appearing on Windows 10 1809 version only. 
Attaching screenshots from my IIS below.

Can anyone suggest what could be the possible issue?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to set the below setting in iis:

- open iis, Select Website
- Select ‘Configuration Editor’
- Select
  ‘system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication’
- useAppPoolCredential to True

Make sure both WCF and the .net application URL using the same protocol.

set the application pool user to the domain account.

at client configuration set below code:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

you could refer below link for more detail:L

[401 Client 'Negotiate', Server 'Negotiate,NTLM' When Calling WCF Server to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460150/401-client-negotiate-server-negotiate-ntlm-when-calling-wcf-server-to-serve)